# SignalR-Objc SRHubConnection delegates not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Working on chat app where we are using signalR-Objc and CocoaPods (to manage dependency).
downloaded SignalR_Objc from https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC
Now
I Am able to establish connection with server
with these lines

```
@interface AQViewController : UIViewController<SRConnectionDelegate>
{
    SRHubConnection *connection;
    SRHubProxy *hub;
}



@implementation AQViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *server = [Router sharedRouter].server_url;
    connection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:server];

    hub = [connection createHubProxy:@"ConvoService"];
    [connection setDelegate:self];

    [connection start];

 }
```

connection also get established with no problem

but when i invoke some method on server, it got invoked because i can see log an server and also db get populated with corresponding data..but the problem is my delegate methods for SRHubConnection are not being called.

//Code

```
@interface AQViewController : UIViewController<SRConnectionDelegate>
{
    SRHubConnection *connection;
    SRHubProxy *hub;
 }


-(IBAction)connect:(id)sender;
@end



#import "AQViewController.h"
#import "Router.h"

@interface AQViewController ()

@end

@implementation AQViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    connection = [SRHubConnection    connectionWithURL:@"http://medcomm.w08dev2.in.aquevix.com"];

   hub = [connection createHubProxy:@"ConvoService"];
   [connection setDelegate:self];

    [connection start];

}



-(IBAction)connect:(id)sender{
       NSString *authKey = @"815f35c0-1cfc-4154-a0c8-7ccb80465c6f23b7d170-3fa4-4a56-   ad50-27c1d5f0390e";

    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dic setValue:authKey forKey:@"AuthKey"];

    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic, nil];
    NSLog(@"arr %@",arr);

   [hub invoke:@"Connect" withArgs:arr completionHandler:^(id u){
    NSString *str = (NSString *)u;


    NSLog(@"Got connect response %@",str);
    }];

}
```

//these delegates are not being called when invoking method on server but are called when request for connection

#pragma mark -
   #pragma mark SRConnection Delegate

```
- (void)SRConnectionDidOpen:(SRConnection *)connection
 {
   //AQSK
   NSLog(@"get connected using HubConnection");


 }

  - (void)SRConnection:(SRConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSString *)data
  {
     //AQSK

     NSLog(@"data recieved %@",data);

  }

   - (void)SRConnectionDidClose:(SRConnection *)connection
  {
     NSLog(@"close");
  }

   - (void)SRConnection:(SRConnection *)connection didReceiveError:(NSError *)error
  {
     NSLog(@"error%@",error.description);
   }
```

Any idea ?? Please help.

Comment: Try logs in the last two method ,may beit will hit

Comment: Added log to check whether these methods being called but nothing happened

Comment: @sunitaKumari can you give me idea how to send text message to server with SignalR-Objc library because can't send message on server.

Comment: why dont you put the connection string ( in viewDidLoad) to connect function and try?